# Call out the city name using maxmind geoip2

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I use this simple code to call out the city name using maxmind service (geoip2). It works perfectly and I got this code from someone on this site too, thanks to him.

The problem is when the user's location doesn't belong to any city, then nothing appears, my headline will look stupid like this "abc offer from..."

When this script can't call out the city name, then replace with "your city".

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//j.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js"></script>

<script>
geoip2.cityISPOrg(function (response) {

$("#city").html(response.city.names.en);

}, null, { w3cGeolocationDisabled: true });
</script>

<p>
 <span id="city"></span>,
</p>
```

Comment: you mean if there is no  city then ,you want to display "No city" or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geoip2.cityISPOrg(function (response) {

  if (response && response.city && response.city.names && response.city.names.en) {
    $("#city").html(response.city.names.en);
  }
  else {
    $("#city").html("your city");
  }
}, null, { w3cGeolocationDisabled: true });
```

Comment: Thank you Johan. I tried our script and it worked perfectly. This is awesome, much much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use following simple code ,and modify according to your need

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var onSuccess = function(location){
    alert(
        "Lookup successful:\n\n"
        + JSON.stringify(location, undefined, 4)
    );
};

var onError = function(error){
    alert(
        "Error:\n\n"
        + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 4)
    );
};

geoip2.city(onSuccess, onError);

</script>
```

Comment: All errors are passed in a JavaScript object as the first parameter to the onError function. This object contains two keys, code and error. code is a machine-readable error code that will not change. error is a human-readable description of the error.

Comment: Thank you Pratik Joshi, actually I tried the script from the guy above and it worked! My horrible coding skill does not allow me to modify anything much, but thank alot for your answer. I didnt expect to get answers this quick!